# estimation of covariance of function of two i.i.d. data points

Tags: estimation, covariance, unbiased-estimator, dependent-variable, u-statistics

Given i.i.d. data: $X_1,\dots,X_n$ living in some space $\mathcal{X}$ and drawn according to distribution $P$, and symmetric functions $f,g: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$, I want to estimate the covariance terms:

$$
\gamma = \text{Cov} (f(X,X'), f(X,X''))
$$

and

$$
\theta = \text{Cov} (f(X,X'), g(X,X''))
$$

where $X, X', X''$ are independent draws from $P$. What is the best way (unbiased or consistent estimation) to estimate these quantities from the given data?

**Some more context:** the $f$ and $g$ functions here are symmetric kernel functions for my U estimators, so $U_n := \frac{1}{{n \choose 2}} \sum_{i<j} f(X_i, X_j)$ and similarly for $g$. My goal is to use results about the asymptotic joint distribution of U statistics (see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3979276/151735), in which I state this result) which requires consistent estimation of the covariance quantities listed above. I would just like to understand how in practice such quantities may be estimated that would in turn allow me to use these asymptotic results to build confidence intervals

Comment: It depends on $f,$ $g,$ $P,$ and what you mean by "best."  Otherwise about all you can hope for is a recapitulation of the theory of estimation, which is too broad for this site.  Could you provide those details, then?

Comment: @whuber well in the title I ask for a way to compute an unbiased estimator, i should not have said 'best' later on in the question - this question is based on computing the asymptotic variance for U statistics, the 'f' and 'g' are symmetric kernels for my U statistic of degree 2, and so I am looking for a general result that allows me to estimate these variance terms

Comment: @whuber thanks for reopening, I've also added some more clarification in the question